# Populate dropdown list with current day, month and year using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dropdown

I found a question that interests me and a solution to it is here on this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660131/17222337, but it's in jQuery, but I'm interested in a pure javascript solution. I reviewed what I could do, but found only non working code on this topic in pure javascript. I tried to translate from jQuery into javascript, but the code I get is wrong and does not work. Tell me please,
how to make a javascript code from the given jquery code?

Comment: You already have the answer. Read the code and understand it then replace jquery elements with js (there is very few jquery). If you dont understand this code you wont understand the code anyone else here would post.

Comment: The jQuery part is minimal.

Comment: From a very quick look, the only jquery used is the `ready` event, which can be changed to `window.addEventListener('load', () => { /**/ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
form span{
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
/*make form styling consistent across browsers*/
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
  }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <form>
        <span>
            <label for="day">Day:</label>
            <select name="day" id="day"></select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <select name="month" id="month"></select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="year">Year:</label>
            <select name="year" id="year">Year:</select>
        </span>
    </form>
    <script>
        //Create references to the dropdown's
const yearSelect = document.getElementById("year");
const monthSelect = document.getElementById("month");
const daySelect = document.getElementById("day");

const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 
'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
'November', 'December'];

//Months are always the same
(function populateMonths(){
    for(let i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.textContent = months[i];
        monthSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
    monthSelect.value = "January";
})();

let previousDay;

function populateDays(month){
    //Delete all of the children of the day dropdown
    //if they do exist
    while(daySelect.firstChild){
        daySelect.removeChild(daySelect.firstChild);
    }
    //Holds the number of days in the month
    let dayNum;
    //Get the current year
    let year = yearSelect.value;

    if(month === 'January' || month === 'March' || 
    month === 'May' || month === 'July' || month === 'August' 
    || month === 'October' || month === 'December') {
        dayNum = 31;
    } else if(month === 'April' || month === 'June' 
    || month === 'September' || month === 'November') {
        dayNum = 30;
    }else{
        //Check for a leap year
        if(new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() === 1){
            dayNum = 29;
        }else{
            dayNum = 28;
        }
    }
    //Insert the correct days into the day <select>
    for(let i = 1; i <= dayNum; i++){
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = i;
        daySelect.appendChild(option);
    }
    if(previousDay){
        daySelect.value = previousDay;
        if(daySelect.value === ""){
            daySelect.value = previousDay - 1;
        }
        if(daySelect.value === ""){
            daySelect.value = previousDay - 2;
        }
        if(daySelect.value === ""){
            daySelect.value = previousDay - 3;
        }
    }
}

function populateYears(){
    //Get the current year as a number
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    //Make the previous 100 years be an option
    for(let i = 0; i < 101; i++){
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = year - i;
        yearSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
}

populateDays(monthSelect.value);
populateYears();

yearSelect.onchange = function() {
    populateDays(monthSelect.value);
}
monthSelect.onchange = function() {
    populateDays(monthSelect.value);
}
daySelect.onchange = function() {
    previousDay = daySelect.value;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```